# Getting digits in an order (left to right) after OCR from x,y coordinates

Tags: python, ocr

So I wrote an OCR script which grabs image and performs OCR and return x,y coordinates with the digit , when i plot it i get the underlying image.

[image: ocr image plot]

The x,y coordinates with digits are not predicted sequentially but as the contours are detected (almost randomly).

Is there a way to get them to arrange in a readable left to right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to get the x, y coordinate pairs, you can sort by y, then x values.

```
xy_list = ((2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0),
           (2, 2), (1, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0))
xy_list = sorted(xy_list, key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0]))
print(xy_list[:3])
print(xy_list[3:6])
print(xy_list[6:])
```

Gives

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

This won't account for slight variations in y values that should be considered on the same line, but are slightly off-center.

#### EDIT

This lets the y vary by the specified offset. (So you could set it to 10.0, in your case). Note that I'm using Python 3, so if you're using 2, make sure you make offset a float.

```
offset = .5
xy_list = ((2, 1), (1, 2.1), (0, 1), (1, 0.1), (0, 0),
           (2, 1.6), (1, 1.3), (0, 2), (2, 0.3))
xy_list = sorted(xy_list, key=lambda tup: (
    round(tup[1]/(2*offset)), tup[0]
))
```

Gives

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0.1), (2, 0.3)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1.3), (2, 1)]
[(0, 2), (1, 2.1), (2, 1.6)]
```

Comment: the slight variations in y values are the only problem , i want something that sorts in range like : for values of y in range (y+10) to range (y-10) ; so as to take care of the minor offsets.

Comment: thanks man your idea was awesome , can u tell me more about this "key = lambda" thing or just guide me to a link. Cheers !!

Comment: Yeah definitely! The "lambda x" syntax is called an anonymous function. Anonymous functions are used in many different cases (google it to learn more), but in this case, its a function that is applied to each element of the list, returning the element (or elements) to compare for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you have a list of tuples of the form `(x,y,digit)` and you want to sort them into lines, you could try something like:

```
L = [(1.1,1.4,'2'),(1.3,.1,'3'),(0.1,.1,'1')]
linewidth = 20
L2=  sorted(L, key = lambda coords: ((coords[0]-linewidth/2)%linewidth, coords[1]))
L2
[(0.1, 0.1, '1'), (1.1, 1.4, '2'), (1.3, 0.1, '3')]
```

Comment: there are slight variations in y values for a line of characters are the only problem , i want something that sorts in range like : for values of y in range (y+10) to range (y-10) ; so as to take care of the minor offsets.

Comment: I've changed linewidth to 20 and added a scale factor of linewidth/2 in the rounding part (% is the modulus operator in Python). Does this makes sense?

Comment: there is something happening but I don't know what exactly. I tried your method to sort this list of tuples(digit,x,y) : [(1, 121, 33),
 (1, 123, 66), (1, 120, 99), (1, 161, 33), (1, 160, 66), (1, 162, 99)] and got this after sorting [(1, 160, 66), (1, 120, 99), (1, 121, 33), (1, 161, 33), (1, 162, 99), (1, 123, 66)]  as U can see sorting did happen but not to much use.

Comment: Hey Manipal, if your coords are in the 2nd and 3rd position, you'll have to change the code to coords[1] and coords[2]. (in my example, I had the coords in the first and second position). Note the Python is 0 indexed!